# How does Airflow parses DAG from a file?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I would want to ask how does Airflow parses a DAG like the following with Python?

```
[a] >> [b, c] \
    >> [d]
```

Is it possible to create such a DAG with networkx? I am looking for a way for a much simpler way of denoting DAG like Airflow.

Comment: Can you please be more clear to help us understand your requirement better? I assume a, b, c and d are tasks inside a DAG

Comment: Is it possible to build a parser like Airflow that can read 
`[a] >> [b, c] \>> [d]`
from a file and then show it as a graph with networkx with Python?